# How to UPDATE just one record in DB2?

Tags: mysql, db2, transaction

In **DB2**, I need to do a [`SELECT FROM UPDATE`](http://db2portal.blogspot.com/2007/04/select-from-delete-update-and-merge-db2.html), to put an update + select in a single transaction.
But I need to make sure to *update only one record* per transaction.

Familiar with the `LIMIT` clause from [MySQL's `UPDATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html) option

> places a limit on the number of rows that can be updated

I looked for something similar in [DB2's `UPDATE` reference](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0001022.html) but without success.

How can something similar be achieved in DB2?

Comment: Simply include a WHERE condition on the primary key column(s). That ensures that only a single row will be updated.

Comment: Why did you repost the question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8735428/how-to-update-just-one-record-in-db2

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name looking for a wider "audience".

Comment: @MariusButuc - did you try the cursor with update? did it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, on the link you have, it mentions that you **can** update only one record, you just have to use cursors to do so. It then points you to the [`DECLARE CURSOR` page](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000937.html).

So first, you would have to declare a cursor from your table with the select statement that would give you what you want.

```
DECLARE C1 CURSOR
FOR (SELECT * FROM MYTABLE WHERE...);
```

Move to the value of the record in the cursor that you want.

Then run you update statement against the cursor using the link you mention

```
UPDATE MYTABLE 
SET MYCOLUMN = ?
WHERE CURRENT OF C1;
```

I believe you need to issue a `COMMIT` (which closes the cursor unless you specify otherwise in the `DECLARE CURSOR` clause).

Check out the documentation in the link you have and in the one I have. You may end up having to use a stored procedure to run this.